# When and why is it necessary to remove an event?

Tags: javascript, events

When and why should I remove an event listener? Is it bad, or bad practice to leave all events there? What if a `div` is hidden, do I still need to remove the event before I hide it?

Comment: Can the down-voters explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When and why should I remove an event?

Several reasons:

- Old browsers had a memory link where you added event to element and once the element removed from the DOM the event was not removed (memory leak)
- Good coding - If you added event - remove it as well
- Performance - Less code in memory = faster execution time

> Is it bad, or bad practice to leave all events there?

As explain before - **no**, since the JS engine will know how to take care of that and to remove it.

> What if a div is hidden, do I still need to remove the event before I hide it?

No.

Comment: If I hide a div, will there be faster performance if I remove the event?